# Is it possible to create a private Ethereum blockchain that runs on AWS and communicates with the public mainnet?

Tags: blockchain, ether, etherscan, aws

*I have a question: Is it possible to create a private Ethereum blockchain that runs on AWS and communicates with the public mainnet?*

I discovered that there are several ways to connect the private ethereum blockchain to AWS.

1. Use **Amazon Managed Blockchain**: It allows you to choose only Hyperledger Fabric, but the latter has a framework (called Hyperledger Burrow) for creating ethereum nodes within it and to communicate, at least I think, with the public Ethereum blokchain;
2. With **Amazon EC2** and **blockchain templates**, which help enterprises to build their blockchain networks on AWS cloud infrastructure.

Which choice is the easiest and fastest, but above all feasible for my purpose?
Do you know anyone else?

Answer (score 0):

Amazon Managed Blockchain will allow you to create either hyperledger fabric or Ethereum node which does not achieve your original goal.

For number 2 Amazon ec2 may not be enough, you would require Kubernetes to deploy a min setup(4/3 node) which is the recommended way, then you would require a relayer for cross-chain messaging. This would definitely be able to accomplish your goal but deployment would be slow.

Alternative approach: You can use Kaleido platform for Polygon Edge, with ChainBridge you can do cross-chain tx. you can have the setup up and run within 2-3 hrs. Certainly this would be faster and easier to maintain.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Are you basically telling me that Amazon Managed Blockchain allows me to create a private blockchain but it's impossible to communicate with the public Ethereum blockchain? For your alternative using Kaleido, could you give me more information? Is it possible to connect the chain on AWS? how does it work specifically?